# Symfony Assetic watch: Only process changed files in debug

Tags: symfony, assetic

I use this code to include my less files:

```
{% stylesheets "@MyBundle/Styles/*.less" %}
 <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

If I use the dump/watch command this compiles all less files on a change. 
In production / no-debug mode this is fine because the files get combined in a single file.

In dev mode the files are served individual for easier debugging. Nevertheless all files are always recompiled (even if just a single file has changed) which slows down development a lot for me.

So is it possible to recompile only the changed files in dev/debug mode?

Comment: Maybe `assets:install --symlink` doesnt slow down performance ?

Comment: What about less processing? I think it's not possible with `assets:install --symlink` is it?

Comment: A related question (which they partially solved by creating their own dump command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771043/symfony2-assetic-dont-generate-composite-file-on-env-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I had some more problems with assetic I ended up by completely replacing it by [gassetic](https://github.com/romanschejbal/gassetic) which is based on gulp and has a lot of advantages (see readme on github)...